# sudo passwd on Ubuntu 11.10 strange behavior. Have I been rooted?

Tags: ubuntu, security, password, flooding, botnet

I'm in a really strange situation. A few hours ago Rackspace issued a ticket saying there's a outbound flood originating from my server.

Thinking the server might have been rooted with a rootkit I ran chkrootkit scans and nothing showed up.

So I decided to change ssh password and this is what happened.

```
$ passwd <<username>>
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

When I did the exact same thing on another Ubuntu 11.10, this happened.

```
$ passwd <<username>>
Changing password for username.
(current) UNIX password:
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Hence, on one server ( suspected to have been attacked ) passwd command doesnt ask for "previous" password before changing the password. On the other server it does.

I checked nginx access logs and found http calls originating form "localhost". I think there might be a suspicious script running on the server.

It could be possible that the system is compromised?

Lastly, I'd like to ask if someone knows of a good rootkit scan I could run on the server. I'm not asking for a silver bullet but something you guys usually use. I'm fairly new to server security.

Thanks guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 3):

When you run `passwd` as root, you are not prompted for the old password. As any other user, you are prompted for the old password.